# Probability and proof of a coin toss

Tags: probability

I don't know how to ask this more generally. So I will use the classic example of a coin toss. My question is, as the number of experiments of a coin toss goes to infinity, is there a mathematical proof that the probability of getting a heads or a tails does indeed go to 1/2?

Comment: This thing(in this case) comes  binomial probability distribution.

Comment: The probability of getting either a heads or a tails, in every toss, is exactly 1/2. It sounds like you may be wondering about the Law of Large Numbers, which states (in this case) that the total number of heads divided by the total number of coin tosses approaches 1/2 as the total number of tosses approaches infinity. This is a provable mathematical statement.

Comment: Yes @anon! You summarized my question better than I...and after a cursory look at the Law of Large Numbers, it looks like the proof I'm asking about is Chebyshev's inequality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's so called Borel's law of large numbers, you can look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers)

Answer (score 0):

When you take the number of times you got heads (or tails) and divide it by the number of times you made a toss (let's say *n*), the result becomes a random variable itself, which if I'm not mistaken is defined as the *frequency*. If *p* is the theoretical probability of getting heads (or tails), then the *expected value* (or the mean) of the frequency is *p*, and its standard deviation is proportional to $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$, which in theory means the frequency approaches p as n goes to infinity.

This comes from the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers), and the definition of p itself as the number of times you got heads (or tails, or a success in any experiment involving a random variable) divided by the number of tosses (or times you experimented) as they approach infinity also arises from this.

If you were talking about a mathematical proof that shows that this limit is actually $\frac{1}{2}$ without infering it from experiments (or reason, I guess), I don't know if there exists such proof. I'm sorry.